# Deploying .pyc only on embedded linux platform

Tags: python, embedded, pyc

Is there any contraindication in deploying .pyc only files in and embedded systems running Linux and python 2.7 ?

If I can deploy only .pyc I would avoid having waste of storage in a resource constrained embedded system.

Comment: have you tried it? I would expect it to work fine ... (although you might need to create the pyc on the target system (Im not sure))

Comment: Beware that .pyc files are not guaranteed to be portable.  They are Python version specific and also architecture specific - big/little endian issues, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was portable. Anyway I can compile them in target.